# margin: 0 auto; not centering div in parent

Tags: html, css

I have the following div arrangement, with the below css. Everywhere online seems to say you need margin:0 auto; for centering, but the text still goes to the top right,

Any help appreciated.

```css
.menu_item {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div style='position:absolute;width:110%;height:110%;left:-5%;top:-5%;background-color:white;z-index:7;overflow:none;'>
  <div id='menu_but' style='width:36px;height:36px;'>
    <div class='menu_line' />
    <div class='menu_line' />
    <div class='menu_line' />
  </div>
  <div id='menu'>
    <div class='menu_item'>HOME</div>
    <div class='menu_item'>ABOUT US</div>
    <div class='menu_item'>CONTACT US</div>
    <div class='menu_item'>PORTFOLIO</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you are setting width:36px to their parent so its centred inside that width

Comment: You have some glaring HTML issues. You cannot self close a div `<div class='menu_line' />` That is invalid

Comment: @TemaniAfif the menu items aren't children of the `menu_but` element.

Comment: @disinfor they are because the HTML is invalid

Comment: Well, yeah, but I think that would have been better to point out :)

Comment: If you want to centre the text within the `.menu_items` just use `text-align: center`. The margin trick will not work because the divs are 100% width of their parent.

Comment: thanks, changed it, but still an issue, I'm trying to center the home, portfolio, etc, the class "menu_item"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe use flexbox ?

```
.parent {
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;
}
```

All of the child elements will be centered

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `<div>` is not a self-closing tag so you have to write `</div>` instead of `<div class='menu_line'/>`

Then, you could simply do:

```css
<style>
.menu_item{
    display: inline-block;
}
#menu {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
```

```html
<div id="menu">
    <div class="menu_item">HOME</div>
    <div class="menu_item">ABOUT US</div>
    <div class="menu_item">CONTACT US</div>
    <div class="menu_item">PORTFOLIO</div>
</div>
```

Comment: display: inline-block only works horizontally though, is there a way to center it vertically aswell in pure css?

Comment: You did not specify that you'd need both horizontally and vertically centering... Use flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/